# Under which conditions a symmetric matrix $S$ can be written as $A^TA$?

Tags: matrices

Let $\mathbb{F}$ by a field.
Under which conditions a symmetric matrix $S\in \mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$ can be written as $A^TA$, where $A\in\mathbb{F}^{k\times n}$?

Comment: I think that is "Iff every eigenvalue is a square in $\mathbb F$ and $S$ has rank at most $k$"

Comment: @Exodd I do agree with the rank condition, but where does the other condition come from?

Comment: over the reals, $A^TA$ is positive semi-definite; the eigenvalues are positive (therefore squares of reals) or zero

Comment: @Will Is it a sufficient condition as well?

Comment: Hmmm... It seems more complicated than I originally thought. Finite fields usually do not behave well with diagonalization, and even $\mathbb C$ has non-diagonalizable symmetric matrices. My first claim is also false, since there exists a counterexample in $\mathbb F_2$